# What is the time window in which we can use the login url provided by Site.login()?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, digital-experience

I am using the standard Site.login() method to log a user into a Salesforce Digital Experience site.  I basically have an Apex controller class in the backend that receives a Username and Password.  Executes the Site.login() method and returns the login URL to the LWC component on the frontend which then re-directs a user to the sites' home page.  There is a button that the user needs to complete for the redirect to happen.

What I have noticed is that if a user receives the login URL successfully but it clicks the button to redirect them within 2 minutes of receiving the login URL it works perfectly.

However, If the user waits more than 2 minutes before being redirected using the login URL.  I get a site error stating that the web socket has closed and I get a "Site is temporarily unavailable error" on the front end.

Is this by design?  Does salesforce have a timer on how long a login URL is valid for?